# Accessing PHP page downloads file instead of processing / parsing PHP

Tags: wordpress

When I moved my website from one host to another, this error started happening: http://eldwa.com/

This is the code of the htaccess

```html
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php56” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddType application/x-httpd-ea-php56 .php .php5 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

Comment: Don't use "text-speak" (such as plz) - spell it out.

Comment: This is impossible to answer, as we don't know the specifics of your hosting (what version of PHP? Does your server use ea to handle PHP requests? etc) - Also - contact your new host provider? They should be able to fix this up for you.

Answer (score 0):

You actually need to contact your hosting service provider with the issue as they have the root access of the server and they will be able to fix the issue for you.